# Obtain instance of polymorphic class at runtime in Scala

Tags: scala

Code sample illustrating what I'm aiming for:

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class C[A](implicit ct: ClassTag[A]) {
  def inst: A = ct.runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A]
}

val c = new C[String]
c.inst
//=> res8: String = ""
// So far so good

val className = "C"
val typeParam = "String"
```

How do I use `className` and `typeParam` to obtain an instance of `C[String]` at runtime (using Scala `2.11.5`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hum ... That looks very suspicious, but anyway, you should be able to get it like this:

```
Class.forName(className).getConstructor(classOf[ClassTag[_]]).newInstance(
    ClassTag(Class.forName(typeParam)))
```

- You'll need fully qualified names in `className` and `typeParam`.
- The class referenced by `className` must have a constructor with one parameter of type `ClassTag`.
- It will blow up if anything's amiss.

What do you think you need this for? There should be a better to achieve your end goal.

Comment: The class responsible for querying in a distributed system. A query comes in, class is dynamically determined according to query, then the query is distributed to `N` nodes, with determined class encoded as a `String`. Each of those nodes should instantiate the class. Part of the challenge is bolting this on to an existing system that uses a `className: String`. Thanks for the answer, I'll try that out!

Comment: One issue: the resulting instance is of type `Any`, so I can't call my `inst` method on it. I've tried various `asInstanceOf` incantations but no luck yet.

Comment: What do you mean, of type `Any`? The *static type* is of course `Any`, but there is no way around that: how would you get a *static* type from a *dynamic class name*? If you are sure there is such an `inst` method (by name), you can again use reflection to call it: `x.getClass.getMethod("inst").invoke(x)` (`x` being the result of the incantation in my answer).